# Java Robot not working on Windows 10 popup

Tags: java, awtrobot

I'm trying to write an automated script to dismiss a Windows 10 popup (image below). The script works fine on other programs (like notepad), but does not work on the popup screen:

```
public class RobotClicker
{
    static Robot robot; 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException
    {   
        robot = new Robot();
        robot.delay(5000);    
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);
        robot.delay(100);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);
        robot.delay(100);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.delay(100);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.delay(100);
    }   
}
```

[image: Windows "User Account Control" popup]

The popup seems to be disabling action from all other programs (it even disables my screen video capture as long as the popup is active). How can I get around this?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad Windows blocked such dangerous action. You may have to look for a native solution anyway.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25982041/is-it-possible-to-click-on-windows-uac-dialog-using-java-awt-robot